# ggmap does not display map called inside a function

Tags: r, ggmap, stamen-maps

My ggmap() code to overlay contour plots on a Stamen Map works perfectly until I put it inside a function. Then it stops displaying the map, although all the parameters etc are correctly passed.
Here's the code:

```
ggmap(stamenMapObject) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn", direction = -1) +
    geom_contour_filled(data = df, alpha = 0.5, aes(x = lon, y = lat, z = z),
                        breaks    = myBreaks)
```

Any thoughts on what might be wrong? Some kind of scoping issue I've missed in R?

Weirdly, the code works if I put a Debug breakpoint at the ggmap call inside the function, then inside Debug Execute the Next Line using CMD-Enter, or copy and paste the code into the Console. So clearly all the parameters, packages etc are set correctly.

But inside Debug it DOES NOT WORK if I try to execute it using (Mac) F10 or 'c' or 'n' in the console.

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If it is inside a function you need to explicitly print it.  Try `g<- ggmap(....` then `print(g)`

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot @Dave2e! For info, why is this? Could you point me to a manual page somewhere that might explain this?

Comment: It is a variable scope thing.  I am sure it is somewhere in the R introduction. If you are expecting output inside a function or "sourcing" a script you need to explicitly call a print function.